# What states used voting equipment by Dominion Voting Systems for the 2020 election (if any)?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, voting, voting-systems

I heard about that ["Dominion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominion_Voting_Systems) system of electronic voting.

Did any states use it during the 2020 election? And if so, which exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Twenty-eight states used voting equipment from Dominion Voting Systems in 2020. According to an article entitled *Election 2020: Setting the record straight* on [their website](https://www.dominionvoting.com/election2020-setting-the-record-straight/), the company notes that "voting has proceeded smoothly in all 28 states where our systems are used".

Also on their website, Dominion provides a map showing states in which their systems are [used](https://www.dominionvoting.com/about/):

[image]

In list form, these states are: Alaska, Arizona, California, Colorado, Florida, Georgia, Illinois, Iowa, Kansas, Louisiana, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Missouri, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, Ohio, Pennsylvania, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, & Wisconsin. Puerto Rico also uses systems from Dominion, but isn't a state.

Comment: Dominion’s map may lead the reader to believe that their system is used in Ohio. In actuality however Dominion is not used in my Ohio county. A more accurate map would be reveal what voting jurisdictions use Dominion.

Comment: "Use" is probably a very broad category. Colorado has mail-in voting. If people are voting electronically, it must be for special cases.

Comment: I think Texas decertified Dominion and [banned it from their state in 2019](https://www.sos.texas.gov/elections/forms/sysexam/dominion-d-suite-5.5-a.pdf). Not sure why it's still highlighted. Perhaps it's only the states in the blue circles? (Oh, but I just noticed this is discussed in the following answer. Perhaps refer there.)

Answer (score 2):

According to NGO [Verified Voting](https://verifiedvoting.org/verifier/#mode/search/year/2020/make/Dominion%20Voting%20Systems) (as quoted by [Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/uk-factcheck-dominion-software-trump-law-idUSKBN27S2Z9)), 24 states and one unincorporated territory used voting equipment by Dominion Voting Systems in the November 2020 US elections: Alaska, Arizona, California, Colorado, Florida, Georgia, Illinois, Iowa, Kansas, Louisiana, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Missouri, Nevada, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, Ohio, Pennsylvania, Puerto Rico, Tennessee, Virginia, Washington and Wisconsin.

Answer (score 1):

Texas DOES NOT use Dominion Voting Systems.

Per the [publicly accessible PDF from the **State of Texas Secretary of State** document](https://www.sos.state.tx.us/elections/forms/sysexam/dominion-democracy-suite-5.5.pdf) (dated October 2-3, 2019)

> REPORT OF REVIEW OF DOMINION VOTING SYSTEMS DEMOCRACY SUITE 5.5-A.

> **FINDINGS**
>
> The examiner reports identified multiple hardware and software issues that preclude the Office of the Texas Secretary of State from determining that the Democracy Suite 5.5-A system satisfies each of the voting-system requirements set forth in the Texas Election Code. Specifically, the examiner reports raise concerns about whether the Democracy Suite 5.5-A system is suitable for its intended purpose; operates efficiently and accurately; and is safe from fraudulent or unauthorized manipulation. Therefore, the Democracy Suite 5.5-A system and corresponding hardware devices do not meet the standards for certification prescribed by Section 122.001 of the Texas Election Code.
>
> **CONCLUSION**
>
> Accordingly, based upon the foregoing, I hereby deny certification of Dominion Voting Systems' Democracy Suite 5.5-A system for use in Texas elections.

Comment: Doesn't this just apply to the particular 5.5-A system? Could there be other models from the same company in use in Texas?

Comment: They do not appear to have anything but the one software, which is designed around their hardware.

https://www.dominionvoting.com/democracy-suite-ems/

[EDIT] which would/may also imply that Texas, denying this software suite, also rejects their four other product lines:
1- Imagecast X Ballot Marking
Precinct Voting
2- Imagecast Precinct Tabulation
Precinct Voting
3- Imagecast Central  Tabulation
and 
4- Imagecast Evolution Tabulation Ballot Marking Device.

Comment: Similar to @JJJ, I note that this finding was made more than a year before the general election, and that there is nothing to say that Dominion didn't subsequently correct the cited "issues" and win both certification and one or more contracts in Texas.

Answer (score 0):

Person claims that Texas Board of Elections dumped Dominion systems in 2018 because the systems are vulnerable to "undetected and unauditable manipulation" p. 8  https://www.scribd.com/document/485884541/Complaint-Cj-Pearson-v-Kemp-11-25-2020#download&from_embed